# How can I set custom colors values in a Xaml Value field?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I have some XAML like this:

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

How can I set the color `Red`, to something like `250 200 150`? I tried `Color 250 200 150`, and `250 200 150`, but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use HTML-style colors.

```
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0000"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
```

Or, if you want alpha transparency:

```
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#80FF0000"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
```

Or using your example color of 250,200,150:

```
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAC896"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I convert colors from RGB to HTML easily in VS? I mean I think in RGB and HSV, but not HTML :O

Comment: When I say "HTML colors", is was referring to the format of the specifier, not the color space. The format is `#RRGGBB` or `#AARRGGBB`, with R, G, and B in hex, not decimal.

Comment: Thanks, that's good but I don't know how to do in my head. Like when I see 255 217 220, I think of light red, and vice versa, or even in HSV, I can quickly imagine the color in my head. But doing this in HEX in my head, never did it and seems like I need a calculator for it, right?

Comment: Windows Calculator can do it for you: Use Scientific view, type in your number, and switch it from "Dec" to "Hex".

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will be stuck with HEX colors.

Answer (score 22):

Sorry, I was wrong here. The way to use this is with floating point values ranging from 0 to 1.

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2"> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="sc#1.0,0.7,1.0,0.5"></Setter> 
</Trigger>
```

To use ARGB values we must use this, a little less straight forward

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2"> 
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                    <Color A="255" R="250" G="200" B="150"/>
                </SolidColorBrush.Color>
            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Trigger>
```

**Update**
You could also use a custom `MarkupExtension`

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2"> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{markup:BrushFromArgb 255, 250, 200, 150}"/>
</Trigger>
```

*BrushFromArgbExtension*

```
public class BrushFromArgbExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public BrushFromArgbExtension() { }
    public BrushFromArgbExtension(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    public byte A { get; set; }
    public byte R { get; set; }
    public byte G { get; set; }
    public byte B { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
    }
}
```

And a similar `MarkupExtension` could also be used for `Color`

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{markup:FromArgb 255, 255, 200, 150}"/>
```

*FromArgbExtension*

```
public class FromArgbExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public FromArgbExtension() { }
    public FromArgbExtension(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }

    public byte A { get; set; }
    public byte R { get; set; }
    public byte G { get; set; }
    public byte B { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's that's gold. Do you know what sc mean? Also do you know if this is any slower or faster than using HTML colors in terms of program performance? I remember a friend telling me WPF uses HTML colors because they are faster to parse.

Comment: Good question, what does scRGB stand for? Anyone? :) I don't believe that there's any real time difference in the parsing but I can't be sure. However, unless this is a real bottleneck for you than this sounds like premature optimization :)

Comment: You're specifying the colour in scRGB colour space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScRGB

Comment: Yes, I looked at that page but I couldn't find a clear "s" stands for, and "c" stands for. But maybe that wasn't the question to begin with. I probably read it wrong

Comment: Thanks I was curious what sc meant but if it's scRGB, then that's suffice. But I am not sure if scRGB maps 1:1 to RGB, doesn't look like it.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd example, it's longer but still useful.

Comment: @FredrikHedblad This sir was fantastic!  Provided an excellent solution to a longstanding problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @JoanVenge - This is old, but I thought the information could be valuable for someone else. scRGB doesn't map 1:1 to RGB, since scRGB can represent way more colors. In [this old post](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-12-WPF__Welcome_scRGB_-_New_friend_of_Red,_Green,_Blue.aspx) you can see some examples of the equivalence

Answer (score 6):

You can set the "background" property on a XAML control element to be a hex value directly.

```
<Button Background="#292929">
```

And you can add the alpha at the start if you wish as well.

```
<Button Background="#55292929">
```

Learn more [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/02/07/210-specifying-colors-in-xaml-as-rgb-values/)